# Is there any way to hack IDLE (or Python itself) to cut off large prints when working with large text files?

Tags: python, python-idle

I know this is probably a newbie mistake that I deserve generic criticism for, but I was hoping someone had workaround.

I'm trying to work out this program to edit a large number of very large text files. Whenever I work through my code interactively, I'm often screwing up certain parts and accidentally printing the whole dang file. I know how to avoid this by slicing or whatever, but every time I make a mistake I end up crashing IDLE.

I figured someone out there might have a hack for this. Of course, the answer is probably just do it in the terminal/emacs/eclipse, dummy.

Does anyone have a solution, or is this just stuff people put up with?

Comment: I switched to [Dreampie](http://www.dreampie.org/) a while back to help avoid this and haven't looked back.

Comment: For interactive work, [IPython](http://ipython.org/) is hard to beat.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to replace `sys.stdout` to limit the output produced:

```
# override.py
import sys
class LimitedWriter:

    def __init__(self, limit):
            self.limit = limit
            self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
            self.active = True
    def toggle(self, flag):
            self.active = flag

    def write(self, value):
            if len(value) > self.limit and self.active:
                    value = value[:self.limit] + "..."
            self.old_stdout.write(value)

__lw__ = LimitedWriter(15) # limit to 15 characters
sys.stdout = __lw__
```

And then load it in each session:

```
>>> import override
>>> print "(o.o)" * 10
(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)...
>>>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.toggle(False)
>>> print "(o.o)" * 10
(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)(o.o)
```

Comment: This is very cool, and not something I would have thought of doing. Thank you.